# Using xcode, how can I diff between a working copy of a file and the latest commit in the respository?

Tags: xcode, version-control

Using xcode I would like to see a diff between a working copy of a file and the latest commit in the respository.  I know that if I commit I can get the comparison.  And I know I do it from the command line using 'git diff'.  But is there a way to do it from the xcode GUI?

I keep thinking there must be a way to do this, but can't find it.

Answer (score 61):

Here are screenshots.

**Click the Version Editor button in the top-right (highlighted box):**

[image]

**Then, click the revision to compare with (footer highlighted box):**

[image]

---

**Also, you can navigate through each change using these buttons: `<` and `>`**

[image]

---

**Finally, you can undo a single change with "Discard Change" like so:**

[image]

Comment: is there anyway that you can get them in a unified format like Github? See [this image](http://ben.balter.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/formatting-diff.png). Currently what Xcode has is split...

Comment: How do you get the remote's latest commit? When I do "git fetch" I still don't the repo's latest commit as an option when comparing commits

Answer (score 12):

Phillip and Donn both have the correct answer but I'm including an additional screenshot to clarify why using the "Show the Version editor" button is the PRECISELY CORRECT ANSWER TO THIS QUESTION.  I'd argue that this should be the accepted answer and all others should be deleted to avoid confusion.  :)

As shown in the screenshow below, "Show the Version editor" presents a split view that is a VISUAL DIFF between selected revisions, which default to your local revision on the left and the most recent repo revision on the right.  The key is to use the arrows centered at the bottom to browse through the individual diffs.  The numbers between the arrows indicate the current diff and the total number of diffs.

[image: Version Editor View]

Answer (score 10):

It's not exactly diff but you can get a side-by-side comparison using the version editor button, just above the word "Editor" at the top-right of your Xcode window.

It's the arrow icon to the right of the Assistant Editor icon on upper right of screen [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9kOE.png). The commit/cancel answer also works. Menu: source_control --> Commit (then cancel).

Comment: I cannot see this - can you add a screenshot?

Answer (score 7):

If you purely want to see the difference with the **previous** commit then you could just follow the shortcuts for **Commit** ie do: <kbd>Opt</kbd> <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>. I find this faster to access. Additionally you will see ALL changes you made and not be limited to a single file.

[image]

If you want to compare with 2-3 commits before then you would have to use the comparison button that other answers have already mentioned.

**EDIT:**

Xcode10 has a **change bar**. See [this moment from WWDC 2018 Source Control Workflows in Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/418/?time=218)

[image]

Answer (score 6):

So, for those poor souls who have updated to Xcode 12 and feels completely lost, just go to `View` -> `Show Code Review`. The old Version Editor (or something alike) will be there.

Comment: If someone is a poor soul who is searching for side by side comparison, change "Inline Comparison" to "Side by side comparison" is the menu next to comparison (to the right of left and right arrows, which symbolize git)

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered a way to do what I want to do.  If you hit the commit button on the repository page you are presented with the commit view which provides an opportunity to diff the about to be committed versions of each file with the latest commit in the current branch.  You can review your diffs and then cancel the commit.